# Uploading/importing large sql database (only differences) mysql/linux

Tags: mysql, linux, import

One more trivial question, sorry if it was answered already but I was unable to find it. I have a large scientific database, which is sometimes updated in-house by our university. Sometimes we want to sync it with the server online to make new data available to everyone.  So I was doing something stupid i.e. dropping all tables and  then

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

I feel that this is not good, **what are the common practices for syncing databases** (probably no need to do full import only differences are needed).

Answer (score 2):

mysqldbcompare will do the job for you. In your description, I assume the only difference between your public database with your in-house database is the new data stored in the in-house database. No schema and old data change.

Let's suppose that server1 is the in-house DB, and server2 is your public DB.

```
mysqldbcompare --server1=user1:password1@in-house \
  --server2=user2:password2@public db1:db2 --changes-for=server2 -a \
  --difftype=sql > sqldiff.sql
```

Then you can import the difference to your public database with command:

```
mysql -u username -p password db_name < sqldiff.sql
```